# MuleSoft: After converting from byte array to string, payload not printing more that 50lines. and ends with [..]

Tags: arrays, string, mule, payload

I got a payload more than 50 lines and it was in byte array.
So after converting from byte array to string, payload not printing more that 50lines.
and ends with [..]

Help me to print complete payload without ending with dots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I resolved my problem by using a groovy, as Byte Array To String is not helpful in these kind of scenarios.

Below is the script I used to resolve.

```
<scripting:transformer doc:name="Groovy to Transform Byte Array To String">
<scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[return payload.join(", ")]]></scripting:script>
</scripting:transformer>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's seems to be a known limitation of logging long strings in Mule. Try writing the string to a file to see if it is correct. I would not recommend to create big log entries anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I use `<logger message="#[message.payloadAs(java.lang.String)]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>` all the time -- for developing, not in Production -- haven't had a problem. Removing Groovy is a plus.